# Variable number of columns of unknown width

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to arrange some number of items in columns. I cannot predict the width or height of the items and I cannot predict the width or height of the container. I also cannot predict how many columns can fit or what width the columns should be. I want the browser to arrange the items in the maximum number of columns that will not exceed the width of the container, minimizing the height of the container.

This solves the problem, but is there a better way? Can it be done without jQuery? Can it be done in a way that degrades gracefully for older browsers that lack features (maybe arrange in rows instead of columns)?

```
<style>
#wrapper {
    column-width: 100px; /* the jQuery will change this */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
.item {
    padding: 50px;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
</style>
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">5</div>
<div class="item">6</div>
<div class="item">7</div>
<div class="item">8</div>
<div class="item">9</div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
// Get the maximum width of the children.
var maxWidth = 0;
jQuery('#wrapper .item').each(function() {
    var width = jQuery(this).outerWidth(true);
        if (width > maxWidth) {
            maxWidth = width;
        }
    });
// Set the column-width of the wrapper to the maximum width.
jQuery('#wrapper').css('column-width', maxWidth + 'px');
</script>
```

Comment: This sounds possible with grid. What browsers do you want to support?

Comment: I want to support all browsers and versions in "common" use. So, basically anything released in the last ten years or so. It doesn't have to look perfect in old browsers, but should be readable (nothing overlapping, obscured or off the edge).

Answer (score -1):

you can use grid for this

```
#wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);   //change 9 to the number of columns
}
```

Comment: The primary requirement is to make the browser figure out how many columns will fit. So, specifying that number in the CSS will not work.

Comment: @ScottE.Lee you could use jQuery to update style according to your needs